# " You can do a 10-minute warm up, 15 minutes of hills". Why "minute" is not in the plural at first?

Tags: grammatical-number

I read the following the whole sentence: "You can do a 10-minute warm up, 15 minutes of hills, and a 5-minute cool-down"
When you write a mix number-time , you don't need plural?

Comment: More info can be found here: https://ell.stackexchange.com/questions/14290/shouldnt-five-minute-walk-be-five-minutes-walk-in-this-sentence

Answer (score 3):

Because you will see that in the first part we are using **a** which is ***singular***.

So, we will always say:

> It's ***a*** ten-***minute*** walk.

And,

> It takes ten ***minutes*** to walk there (without singular)

**Explanation:**

> We often use a number and a noun combination after a determiner such
>   as an article, this, my etc, and functioning as an adjective before a
>   noun and modifying that noun. In this case, the noun signifying a
>   measure of time, distance, amount, weight etc, is used in the
>   **singular**. [(source)](http://random-idea-english.blogspot.com/2014/01/a-ten-minute-walk-ten-minutes-walk.html)

Comment: So you can say "You can do ten minutes warmup"?

Comment: @deadrat  -- You can certainly say "... ten minutes of warmup", just like "15 minutes of hills".

Comment: And you could say "a 15-minute hill climb".

Comment: @HotLicks You certainly can.  Not what I asked.

Comment: @deadrat I've been wondering about this question too. I don't think you can say "do ten minutes warmup", because that simply is not what people say by convention. Similarly, saying "do ten minute warmup" also sounds weird to English ears. The two grammatical structures that _are_ available to us are "do ten minutes of warmup" and "do a 15-minute warmup". And in these latter two convention-approved sentences the singular "a" does make some sense as to why it might modify the plurality of "minute". Citing conventions might not be the most satisfying of answers, but does this make sense to you?